# Errors saving images to database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a OpenFileDialog which will suppose to select photo and save it to database
but the problem is when I access the class when the dialog result of the openFileDialog is OK
it says that `no such table : PhotoFile` when the SavePhoto function is called with following arguments:

**TODO(P J):put values here**

This is what I've tried so far

```
OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();

        d.Filter = ("JPEG Imange (*.jpg|*.jpg|PNG Image (*.png)|All Files*.*");
        if ((d.ShowDialog()) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           SavePhoto(txtID.text,d.fileName);
        }
```

Here's the code for the function

```
        try {
        using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection SQLConnect = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(g_constring)) {
            byte[] photo = FileImageToByte(PhotoFile);
            SQLConnect.Open();
            if (SQLConnect.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
                SQLiteCommand SQLcommand = new SQLiteCommand(SQLConnect);
                SQLcommand = SQLConnect.CreateCommand;
                SQLcommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM PhotoFile WHERE PhotoID = '" + PhotoId + "'";
                SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SQLcommand.Parameters.Clear();

                SQLcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PhotoFile(PhotoID, Photo) VALUES(@EmployeeID, @Photo1)";

                SQLiteParameter SQLparmID = new SQLiteParameter("@EmployeeID", PhotoId);
                SQLparmID.DbType = DbType.String;
                SQLparmID.Value = PhotoId;
                SQLcommand.Parameters.Add(SQLparmID);

                SQLiteParameter SQLparm = new SQLiteParameter("@Photo1", photo);
                SQLparm.DbType = DbType.Binary;
                SQLparm.Value = photo;
                SQLcommand.Parameters.Add(SQLparm);

                SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                bReturn = true;
            } else {
                bReturn = false;
            }
        }
    } catch (System.Exception eX) {
        MessageBox.Show(eX.Message.ToString(), "Error in database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        bReturn = false;
    }
    return bReturn;
}
```

PhotoFile table exist in my database in fact I've tried a Windows form and trigger the function if the `dialog result = ok` but when I used the `openFileDialog` it always produce the error as stated above.

Comment: How this is related to OpenFileDialog? Looks like some particular argument to SavePhoto causes an error, while there is no problem with OpenFileDialog itself.

Comment: Are you sure the problem doesn't lie in your function?  Where exactly does the application break?

Comment: Just wondering why `SavePhoto()` method actually does `DELETE FROM` sql query?

Comment: What is the value of `d.FileName` when you return from the `OpenFileDialog`? That should be the full path name (i.e. "c:\myapp\photos\myphoto.jpg"). Is that the same value that you get in your Windows Forms app?

Comment: I forgot to post the updated code sorry my bad.. The delete there delete the photo if the id has already in the database.

Comment: @PJ, please look at my edits (changed title and added TODO for you). Also somehow all curly braces and semicolons disappeared from the sample after your edit :).

Answer (score 5):

This isn't anything to do with the OpenFileDialog *per se*, it's your SQL query failing and stating that the table doesn't exist (`Photofile`) - so I would suggest that it doesn't and you should either check your table name, or create it if necessary.

Other than that, there is concern over your query: your method indicates that a photo will be *saved* yet you use a `DELETE`. Also, if the table did exist/when you manage to sort the table name correctly, I'd suggest you don't use strings as identifiers. No *saving* going on anywhere.

Comment: Or check the connection string.

Comment: @NickGotch The OP should get a connection error if the connection string isn't proper, unless they're connecting but to the wrong database.

Comment: Not if he hasn't specified teh databse, e.g. it's looking at master, or it's empty, or the user the code is running has doesn't have permission to see the table...

Comment: @NickGotch Well I'm not sure with SQLite, but other than the first instance of your examples, they should get distinct* errors for those in most database engines. *although some might hide the _actual_ meaning.

Comment: The distinct error is no such table, why there isn't is another ball game.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No, I mean if the connection string was empty they'd get a connection error, if they didn't have access they should get a permissions error (but without details of _why_, obviously.) They _could_ be looking in an empty db, potentially master - number of possibilities there.

Comment: Just clearing it up for people, successful connection doesn't mean connected to right db or as the right user, of even the right server, just means you can connect.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AppMain.ConnectionString` is pointing at the wrong database, which does not contain any `PhotoTable` table. You might want to double check it.

Your code deletes the record matching the provided `PhotoID` by the way, it's not saving anything to the database.